# Effect of PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_HANDLE_LIST on child process standard input, standard output, standard error, relationship to STARTF_USESTDHANDLES

Tags: windows, winapi

I've been experimenting with using the Windows API to launch child processes that communicate with the parent process through anonymous pipes. The basic idea is to create one or more pipes in the parent process using `CreatePipe`, and then launch the child process with inherited pipe handles using `CreateProcess` with a `STARTUPINFOEX` argument that specifies the inherited handles in the `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_HANDLE_LIST` attribute.

Experimentally it seems to me that the first element of handle list is used as the child process's standard input, the second is used as it's standard output, and the third is used as it's standard error. I haven't seen any documentation of this behavior, and I didn't expect it because the `STARTUPINFO` fields `hStdInput`, `hStdOutput`, `hStdError` (along with the `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES` flag in `dwFlags`) seem specifically designed to communicate the `CreateProcess` caller's intent with respect to standard handles. Experimentally it seems to me that `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_HANDLE_LIST` overrides `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES`, which I find even more surprising.

So two questions:

1. Is this behavior documented somewhere that I've missed?
2. How do you inherit handles while also using the default behavior for determining the standard handles of the child process?

UPDATE: It turns out that the behavior I was seeing was specific to the application I was launching as the child process. It must have been inspecting the inherited handles and doing something order specific with them. Most Windows applications do not behave that way.

Comment: no such behavior. you mistake. order of handles in array passed to `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_HANDLE_LIST` not play any role

Comment: @RbMm thanks for the response. Turns out the behavior I was seeing was due to the specific application I was launching as a child process, not the Windows API. If you want to submit your comment as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

`PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_HANDLE_LIST` extended attribute is used to explicitly specify exactly which handles a particular process inherits.

[Raymond Chen's blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111216-00/?p=8873) gives more details,

> But all this inheritability fiddling still had a fatal flaw: What if
> two threads within the same process both call Create­Process but
> disagree on which handles they want to be inherited? For example,
> suppose you have a function Create­Process­With­Shared­Memory whose
> job it is to launch a process, passing it a custom-made shared memory
> block. Suppose two threads run this function simultaneously.
>
> ...
>
> Windows Vista addresses this problem by allowing you to pass an
> explicit list of handles you want the bInherit­Handles parameter to
> apply to. (If you pass an explicit list, then you must pass TRUE for
> bInherit­Handles.) And as before, for a handle to be inherited, it
> must be also be marked as inheritable.

And the blog gives detailed code sample and implementation methods.

For anonymous communication between parent-child processes, please refer to:

- [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output)

`PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_HANDLE_LIST` overrides `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES`, it won't make any effect. Instead, the child process will not inherit the handle of the parent process.